# IE 11 ddl tooltip not working C# .net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I'm having problem with my dropdown list tooltip after upgrade from ie9 to ie11.  I have the browser set to view webpage in compatibility mode and also  in the master page but the tooltip still not working correctly.  The tooltip text only show on the selected value and below it.  Ex.  if my ddl has 10 items and my selected value is 5, then 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 have a text tooltip.  NO tooltip showing for 1, 2, 3, 4 when I hover over these values.  Here are the codes:

```
foreach (ListItem _listItem in this.ddl.Items)
{
    string textitem = _listItem.Text + _listItem.Value;
    _listItem.Attributes["title"] = textitem;
}

ddl.Attributes.Add(
    "onmouseover", 
    "this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with IE11 and Chrome:

```
title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

Try this:

```
ddl.Attributes.Add(
    "onmouseover", 
    "title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value");
```

you can use either `text` or `value` for the the `select.options` like:

```
onmouseover="title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text"
```

Here is my full sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select onmouseover="title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it. Base on your example, if my selectedIndex is opel, then only opel and audi tooltips are working. Nothing when I hover my mouse over volvo and saab values.

Comment: No way!!!! I tested it and it works in all scenarios. Use this site copy/paste http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

Comment: I copied and pasted on the w3school.com but it did not work.  I tested with 2 machines, Win7 32bit and Win7 64bit and they both yielded the same result.

Comment: Please try copy and paste these codes and check it out.  I only can see tooltip 3 and tooltip 4. I Can NOT see tooltip 1 and tooltip 2.         <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TooltipTest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option title="Tooltip 1" value="1">Option #1</option>
            <option title="Tooltip 2" value="2">Option #2</option>
            <option title="Tooltip 3" value="3" selected="selected">Option #3</option>
            <option title="Tooltip 4" value="4">Option #4</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>